# Uncorrelated but not independent uniform distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, uniform-distribution, correlation

Let $X = (X_1, X_2)$ be uniform distributed on $\{(-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)\}$.

First of all I want to show that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uncorrelated but not independent.

Secondly I thought about showing that $X_1 - X_2, X_1 + X_2$ are independent  (and thus uncorrelated).

I have thought about it quite some time but I can't figure out a solution, help is appreciated!

Comment: what's the problem with actually computing the correlation and seeing what comes up? It's not numerically hard to do in this case.

Comment: I don't know how to compute this correlation

Comment: Do you know a definition of correlation?

Comment: Yes but somehow I need to find expected values which I am not able to

Comment: Expectation is $\sum_i i f(i)$ where $f$ is the probability distribution and $i$ is the index. Here, you know that the variables are uniformly distributed. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pdf of $X=(X_1,\,X_2)$ is
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} & \text{for } (x_1,x_2)\in Q=\{(-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)\}\\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$
and the variable $X=(X_1,X_2)$ can be represented in tabular form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(X_1,X_2)\\
f(x_1,x_2)
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
(-1,0) & (1,0) & (0,-1) & (0,1)\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are uncorrelated when their correlation coefficient is zero
$$
\rho(X_1,X_2)=\frac{\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(X_1)\mathsf{Var}(X_2)}}
$$
that is if their covariance is zero: 
$$\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=\mathbb E(X_1X_2) − \mathbb E(X_1)\mathbb E(X_2)=0$$

So you have
$$
\mathbb E(X_1X_2)=\sum_{(x_1,x_2)\in Q} x_1x_2 f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{(x_1,x_2)\in Q}  x_1 x_2=0
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb E(X_1)=\sum_{x_1\in Q_1} x_1 f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x_1\in \{-1,0,1\}}  x_1 =0
$$
and the same for $\mathbb E(X_2)=0$:
$$
\mathbb E(X_2)=\sum_{x_2\in Q_2} x_2 f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{x_2\in \{-1,0,1\}}  x_2 =0
$$ So we have
$$
\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=0
$$
and the variable are uncorrelated.

They are not independent:
$$
f_{X_1}(x_1)=\sum_{x_2\in Q_2}  f(x_1,x_2)=\pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 1\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4}}
$$
and
$$
f_{X_2}(x_2)=\sum_{x_1\in Q_1} f(x_1,x_2)=\pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 1\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4}}
$$
and obviously $f(x_1,\,x_2)\neq f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)$ as you can see from the tabular representation
$$
\begin{array}{cc|ccc|cc}
&&&X_2 &&&\\
&f(x_1,x_2) & -1 & 0 & 1 & f_{X_1}(x_1)\\
\hline
&-1 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}\\
X_1&0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2}\\
&1 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}\\
\hline
&f_{X_2}(x_2)&\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} &
\end{array}
$$
It's easy to find that for $Y=X_1-X_2$ we have $$f_Y(y)=\sum_{x_1,x_2|x_1-x_2=y} f(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{x_1\in\{-1,0,1\}} f(x_1,x_1-y)$$
that is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Y\\
f_Y(y)
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In the same way for $Z=X_1+X_2$ we have $$f_Z(z)=\sum_{x_1,x_2|x_1+x_2=z} f(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{x_1\in\{-1,0,1\}} f(x_1,z-x_1)$$
that is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
Z\\
f_Z(z)
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For the joint distribution of $(Y,\,Z)$ we have
$$
f_{Y,Z}(y,z)=\Bbb P(Y=y,\,Z=z)=\Bbb P(X_1-X_2=y,\,X_1+X_2=z)
$$
for $(y,z)\in\{(-1,-1), (-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1)\}$. So for example $$f_{Y,Z}(-1,-1)=\Bbb P(X_1=-1,\,X_2=0)=f(-1,0)=\frac{1}{4}$$
and so on. Thus we have
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(Y,Z)\\
f_{Y,Z}(y,z)
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
(-1,-1) & (-1,1) & (1,-1) & (1,1)\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} &\frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
that is $(Y,Z)$ is uniformly distributed over $Q'=\{(-1,-1), (-1,1),(1,-1),(1,1)\}$
and it is obvious that $$ f_{Y,Z}(y,z)=f_{Y}(y)f_{Z}(z)
$$
that is $Y=X_1-X_2$ and $Z=X_1+X_2$ are independent (and, as a consequence, uncorrelated).

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! Now it's clear to me

Answer (score 0):

$X_1 X_2=0$ so $E[X_1 X_2]=0$ and thus, since $E[X_1]=E[X_2]=0$, the covariance and correlation must be zero.

But, for example, $X_1=1 \implies X_2=0$ so they are not independent